# Parse a string instead of a file for a Laravel Blade template

Tags: php, caching, laravel, file-get-contents, laravel-blade

I need to cache a remote blade template generated by a CMS to keep an application's public interface up to date. Ideally I would be able to use file_get_contents and a cache to check for updates to this once a week.  Is there any way to get Laravel to use the contents of a variable instead of a file as a blade template?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand. Why is a CMS generating a Blade template? And why can’t you parse that Blade template and cache that?

Comment: Laravel only allows for blade templates from the local file system. Our company wide template changes regularly and I need those changes updated automatically.

Comment: I still don’t understand why you can’t use a file-based view?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to get laravel to parse a string as a blade template so I developed this work around that stores the remote template as a local file.
[RemoteViewFinder Gist](https://gist.github.com/eseyden/60dcf9185908b50e5014)