# Use blade in blade

Tags: php, laravel-blade

In my database I save texts that contains blade markup like:

```
Hello {!! $name !!} how are you today.
```

I pass this text to my email template in a variable $text. In the email I use {!! $text !!} to get the text in the mail. However when the email is send it shows the {!! signs instead of the variable (which is also passed). 
How can I save blade markup in my database and pass it to my code where it needs to replace {!! something !!} with the right variable?

**My mail function.**

```
$email = $order->email;
$name = $order->billingname;

 //The text From the database.
$emailText = Email::findOrFail(5);
$mailtext = $emailText->text;

Mail::send('emails.tracktrace', ['text'=>$mailtext'email' => $email, 'name' => $name],
function ($m) use ($code, $email, $name) {
    $m->from('info@domain.com', 'domain');

    $m->to($email, $name)->subject('Track your package!');
});
```

**Update**

I've got a workaround where i do:

```
$mailtext = str_replace('[name]', $name, $mailtext);
```

this way the user can use [name], I would still like to know how to use it with blade only.

Comment: Is this PHP? if yes, remember to use double quotes! Ex.: $name='a'; echo "Hello {!! $name !!} how are you today.";

Comment: can you display send mail function code ?

Comment: Others have created workarounds that might achieve what you're after: [example 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28769358/parse-a-string-instead-of-a-file-for-a-laravel-blade-template) & [example 2](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/898#issuecomment-70317580). You would need to edit these to suit your specific needs, but they might serve as a good starting point.

Comment: @JayDhameliya ive added it.

Comment: So you want the actual variable value which is available in this page?
e.x Hello {!! $name !!} instead you want Hello somename here..
Am i correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't have a blade-string to compiled PHP code without rendering it at the first place. You should try your custom rendering class or invoke Blade.

```
public function send()
{
    $emailText = Email::findOrFail(5);
    $name = $order->billingname;
    $mailtext = \Blade::compileString($emailText->text);
    ob_start();
    eval("?> $mailtext <?php");
    $mailtext = ob_get_clean();
    Mail::send('emails.tracktrace', [
            'text' => $mailtext,
            'email' => $email,
            'name' => $name
        ],
        function ($m) use ($code, $email, $name) {
            $m->from('info@domain.com', 'domain');
            $m->to($email, $name)->subject('Track your package!');
    });
}
```

However it's not safe as there is an `eval`. [Tested in Laravel 5.1]

Also there are some well written packages out there for this specific purpose, like [StringBladeCompiler v3](https://github.com/TerrePorter/StringBladeCompiler/tree/3.0)

Answer (score 0):

I have used the email like below, all the dynamic variables to be replaced are like '{{ $name }}' in the email template.

I created a data array and used it directly with the mail library. This way you can replace multiple dynamic variables in mail template on the go.

You need to keep your text in the email template and use dynamic vales from database.

If your text for the email is dynamic and comes from database, you can use the text in place of the email template in the function and pass $data variables array to replace them all in one go.

```
$data = array('name' => $customer->Name, 'InvoiceID' => $dueinvoice["InvoiceNumber"],'AmountDue' => $dueinvoice["AmountDue"],'DueDate' => $duedate ,'CurrencyCode' => $dueinvoice["CurrencyCode"]); 
\Mail::queue('emails.DueDateNotification',$data, function($message) use($customer)
{
    $message->subject('DueDate Notification');
    $message->to($customer->EmailAddress);
});
```

Another thing is try to use the 'queue' function for mail as its reduces load and add the email to laravel email queue and sent one by one

Hope this helps you :)